# Which Mac models are afflicted with the "repeating keypress" issue?

Tags: keyboard

My Mac is starting to exhibit unwanted key repeats, where tapping a key once will show two keypresses on screen.

This problem is documented at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8536157

Which models are and are not affected by this issue?

Is there any indication of relative occurrence rate across different models?

Answer (score 1):

These models are affected as of 2019-07-16:

- MacBook (Retina, 12-­inch, Early 2015)
- MacBook (Retina, 12­-inch, Early 2016)
- MacBook (Retina, 12-­inch, 2017)
- MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018)
- MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019)
- MacBook Pro (13­-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacBook Pro (13-­inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
- MacBook Pro (13-­inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacBook Pro (13-­inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacBook Pro (15-­inch, 2016)
- MacBook Pro (15-­inch, 2017)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacBook Pro (15-­inch, 2018)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- MacBook Pro (15-­inch, 2019)

Source: https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks

Answer (score -2):

... so yeah, all of them - if it sports a butterfly-spring keyboard, it's covered.

Comment: Not sure how this adds anything which the existing answers doesn't cover already.